# Save components to a list and then conditionally render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I have a webpage that displays a list of buttons and corresponding iframe components. Each time a new button is clicked, a new iframe is displayed and the existing one is removed.

Here is the iframe component:

```
const IframeComp = ({ button }) => {

    return (
      <iframe src={button}></iframe>
    )
  }

export default IframeComp
```

I am loading all the possible iframes--as strings--into a list in `app.jsx` when the app loads like so:

```
  const [iframeComponents, setIframeComponents] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    function loadIframes() {
      let iframes = {}
      for (const iframeUrl of constants.buttonUrls) {
        const iframe = `<IframeComp button=${iframeUrl}></IframeComp>`
        iframes[iframeUrl] = iframe
      }
      setIframeComponents(iframes)
    }
    loadIframes()
  }, []);
```

And passing the `iframeComponents` to the iframe display page file which checks which button is pressed and renders the appropriate iframe.
Of course, the iframes are getting rendered as strings right now. **Is there a way to load/render these IframeComp components in the app.jsx as actual components/html, store them in a list, and then simply display them downstream based on button click?**

Alternatively, I have tried using `html-react-parser` library to simply render the strings as html in the iframe display page file, but this doesn't work as it lowercases the strings, and they'd also have to take time to render on each button click.

Comment: I'm not sure what's at your iframe pages, but why load them all eagerly? It seems like a performance antipattern: can the user realistically interact with them at such a fast pace that loading one (or a few) at a time is not a better pattern? Also, will the user use every frame? If not, is loading all of them a waste of their bandwidth?

Comment: can you provide the code where iframeComponents is rendered

Answer (score 3):

Why not use component directly?

```js
const [iframeComponents, setIframeComponents] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  function loadIframes() {
    let iframes = {};
    for (const iframeUrl of constants.buttonUrls) {
      const iframe = <IframeComp button={iframeUrl}></IframeComp>;
      iframes[iframeUrl] = iframe;
    }
    setIframeComponents(iframes);
  }
  loadIframes();
}, []);
```

What is your actual code for change iframe by button?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to see what's going on here without seeing where you're rendering the iFrame but I'll point you where I think you might find what you're looking for:

Conditional rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Additionally you can actually use the .map function on an array in the render of a component like so:

```
function Comp() {
    return (
        <div>
            {['TestVal1', 'TestVal2'].map((val) => {return (<p>{val}</p>)})}
        </div>
    )
}
```